# Como sair de um loop digitando um valor específico?

Tags: c, loop

Preciso fazer um programa que multiplique os números informados pelo usuário, e quando o mesmo informar 0 (zero), o programa apresenta a multiplicação dos números digitados. Porém, estou em dúvida de como vou fazer isso sem zerar minha multiplicação.

```
 else if(op==2){
    printf("Foi escolhida a multiplicacao:\n\n");
    do{
        printf("Informe os valores desejados e 0 (zero) para concluir:");
        scanf("%d", &valor);
        mult= mult*valor;
        result=mult;
    }while(valor!=0);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Force a saída do laço antes de fazer a multiplicação:

```
else if (op == 2) {
    printf("Foi escolhida a multiplicacao:\n\n");
    do {
        printf("Informe os valores desejados e 0 (zero) para concluir:");
        scanf("%d", &valor);
        if (valor == 0) {
            break;
        }
        mult = mult * valor;
    } while (valor != 0);
    result = mult; //não precisava estar dentro do laço
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/LoopExit2.c).

Fazendo isto, no fundo não precisa da condição no `while`. Poderia fazer um *loop* infinito com `while(1)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
else if (op == 2) {
    printf("Foi escolhida a multiplicacao:\n\n");
    mult=1;
    do {
        printf("Informe os valores desejados e 0 (zero) para concluir:");
        scanf("%d", &valor);
        if (valor != 0)
            mult = mult * valor;
    } while (valor != 0);
    result = mult;
```